# Wordpress website dashboard page or post editor content is not showing but front end data is showing properly

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently I have uploaded my WordPress site onto the server. I have uploaded the WordPress site in a sub-folder under the root folder like that `../root(domain root folder)/WordPress` (where I host the WordPress folder).

Now problem is that any content data in the page or post in the dashboard of my WordPress admin panel is not showing - see image.

[image]

But all data is showing in the front view - see image.

[image]

Comment: Clear the Browser Cache

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a browser cache issue and not an issue happened to the tinymce editor during upgrade; then try to add this to your config file:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Comment: Sorry, my problem is not solved after adding the line in the config file.

Comment: Did you tried to go to your dashboard -> update ; and reinstall the latest version? Also update your themes

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The WordPress dashboard shows all the content you made, and will also show to other users.